# Access to Kubernetes Pods from instance on GCP

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, vpn

Given:

- VPN instance. This instance runs on internal IP 10.6.240.3
- Kubernetes POD running on internal IP 10.6.240.4

Question:
Why is it not possible to ping / curl / access the POD ip from the VPN instance?

What I need to archieve is to connect to the POD ip from inside my local network through the VPN tunnel.

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**
Same applies to NodePorts:
[image]

```
@vpn-gateway:~$ curl -vvv 10.7.244.149:666
* Rebuilt URL to: 10.7.244.149:666/
*   Trying 10.7.244.149...
* TCP_NODELAY set
```

The VPN gateway cannot access the NodePort

**EDIT2:** Service configuration:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: scs-ui
  name: scs-ui
spec:
  clusterIP: None
  ports:
  - name: application
    port: 666
  selector:
    app: scs-ui
```

Comment: Can you share Pod service configuration?

Comment: I added the service configuration in the original question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found an solution:

Create a LB in the address range of the VPN / Kubernetes. This way the request is routed through the VPN into the service from my local mashine.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: elassandra-ingress
  annotations:
    cloud.google.com/load-balancer-type: "Internal"
  labels:
    app: elassandra-ingress
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  loadBalancerIP: 10.164.0.100
  ports:
  - port: 9042
    protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: elassandra
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have not exposed your pod to the internet using any one of service like Nodeport, Load balancer and clusterIp they your pod cannot be accessible outside the kubernetes cluster any how.

Question: Why is it not possible to ping / curl / access the POD ip from the VPN instance?

```
Answer : without exposing pod outside the world you can not ping pod you can do it in kubernetes cluster network or inside cluster only your pod can be resolved, ping possible
```

To acces your pod from local network simply expose port of pod on expose it using load balancer. Nodeport and loadbalancer work with k8s service.

using service expose pod and you can ping and do everything.

Comment: please see the edit in the original question: the vpn gateway cannot access the NodePort as well

Comment: are you using that ip is from ? 10.7.244.149 ?...can you do kubectl svc and share SS

Comment: what do you mean with your last comment? what exactly should i do?

Comment: do one thing remove clusterip none and use type:Loadbalancer........they try to hit loadbalancer ip:666 port of container

Comment: Is it possible to use Loadbalancer with internal ips only? The services that we want to access should ne be accessible from outside of the network

Comment: using internal ip you can not access service outside you have to make loadbalancer get external ip and loadbalancer will be connectted with the service you can access that service on LB IP

Comment: Then this is not what I need. I explain it again: my DB service / pods runs in kubernetes. I have an VPN into the kubernetes cluster. I need to be able to connect to the pod though the tunnel.